# Cocoa - Add some bytes at the end of a file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal, printf, nstask

I'm developing a **Cocoa app** that has to execute some **terminal commands**. One of these looks like:

```
printf "\xc5\x20\x00\x00" >> aFile.txt
```

I tried with **NSTask** (but I'm not sure how to split the arguments):

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/printf"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\"\\xc5\\x20\\x00\\x00\"",
                                             @">>",
                                             @"aFile.txt", nil]];
[task launch];
```

All I get is:

```
printf: missing format character
```

So I think that ">>" is not a printf argument but an internal terminal command.
**How can I simulate that command in Objective C?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the `>>` token is a shell feature, not an argument to printf.

In this example, I'd probably not use the shell to do this, rather I would write the code to do it in Cocoa or plain C (with stdio.h).

However, to use the shell `>>` command, you can send the line to a shell process, which will interpret `>>` correctly.

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",
                                             @"printf \"\xc5\x20\x00\x00\" >> aFile.txt",
                                             nil]];
[task launch];
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method:

```
- (void)setStandardOutput:(id)file
```

and in [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) methods:

```
+ (id)fileHandleForWritingAtPath:(NSString *)path
- (unsigned long long)seekToEndOfFile
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. But... there's a problem: i get "xc5x20x00x00" in the txt file instead of "√&", that i get if i run that command in the terminal